# Performance of OPENROWSET to copy data from one server to another server

Tags: sql, sql-server

1. Can we write a query like

   INSER TNTO Customers SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET( 'SQLNCLI', Remote Server Settings , 'SELECT * FROM Customers)

   Remote Server is on some other server over internet public IP.
2. Will this be faster compared to SqlBulkCopy?

I need to create a slave database which can regularly copy data from server accessible through public IP

Does anyone have any idea on the timeouts and failure over large value tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) can be used **but** it is intended as a one-time method of getting remote data.  If you plan to do this often, use linked servers instead.

Depending on your needs, you might consider db mirroring or log shipping to replicate data.

Comment: db mirroring wont help, unless you use it in conjunction with snapshots

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you can also consider replication to move your data over.

You can read more detail here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151319.aspx

Comment: Replication doesnt work over internet !! it can only be done over LAN.

Comment: actually, you can implement it provided you do some ground work first. i added the URL for the microsoft page that explains how.

Comment: Before coming to StackOverflow i did everything, VPN simply increases too much management time and web sync too... , more complicated setup procedures lead to more chances of failed setup and increasing management time. When we pay MS I expect a visual tool and vizard to do things, otherwise linux isnt bad if we have to read docs and do setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL Server 2008, then you can try Change Data Capture which will allow you to pick up a Delta of changes every time.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx

Comment: Is it advisable to use in bigger tables, 100GB database? with 2/3 GB per day growing?